# Touch ID needed when creating a file in external ssd

Tags: finder, ssd, external-disk, permission, touch-id

I recently bought an external ssd to put my files in it for my Macbook Pro 2019, at first I linked it at Time machine but I withdrew my decision.

The problem is that I didn't use it before time machine, and since i unliked it, it keeps asking me to put my Touch ID to create a new folder, i can't create a folder directly in it through a tier app (for example vscode), is that normal ? Is there a way to change it ? 
I tried to see if I can reset my SSD or set a format but it doesn't seem possible through Finder. 
I appreciate any help or link that can be useful! (I'm new to macOs)

Comment: How is the external SSD formatted (add a screenshot from Disk Utility showing the drive if you are unsure)?

Comment: His format is 'mac os extended', yet i see through disk utility that 32Go are used (what my time machine took), yet he's empty when i go in it. Should i do delete ?

Comment: If you don't have anything important on it, yes, reformatting surely doesn't hurt.

Comment: fixed the problem so far, i can create wherever i am, thank you for making me discover disk utility, very helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the remains Time Machine might have left on the external drive, starting Disk Utility and reformatting the disk (to APFS in case of an SSD) should get you back on track.

Comment: Agreed. 1) Time Machine doesn't really benefit from being on an SSD. 2) If you were using the drive for Time Machine it would have been HFS+. 3) APFS is recommended for SSDs. Once you have the drive reformatted, if it is owned by `root` you will have to authenticate when trying to create a file or folder in the top-level.